# Find all the invertible terms in $F[x]$ where $F$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Let $F$, a field and $F[x]$ the field of all (finite?) polynomials. Find all the invertible terms of $F[x]$.

Let $f\in F[x]$ such that $f=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i$

We want $fg = 1 \implies \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i \cdot \sum_{j=0}^\infty b_jx^j = 1 \implies \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{i+j=k} a_ib_jx^k = 1$

More precisely,
We want $\sum_{i+j=o} a_ib_j x^0 = 1$ and for $k>0$ we want $\sum_{i+j=k} a_ib_jx^k = 0$.

Since $F$ is a field, there's an $b_0$ such that $a_0\cdot b_0 = 1$.

Therefore, all $f = a + 0\cdot x^1 + 0\cdot x^2 + ...$ (constants) are invertible.

Am I right?

Comment: A polynomial is indeed a finite sum, and so you only need $f = \sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$ for some $n$. The question isn't 'meaningless' if $F[x]$ is a field though, as then you would have to *show* that everything is invertible, which is an exercise in itself. Also (pedantic) every field is a ring.

As to how to proceed, you are correct to see that you need the product of two elements to be 1. That means all the coefficients to $x^i$ for $i\neq 0$ have to be 0. What does this imply, given the coefficients are coming from $F$, a *field*?

Comment: I've edited my question. Thank you @Alex. I'm pretty sure I got it (can you conquer?)

Comment: As to the edit(s), yes it's looking good. Be careful though, not *all* of the constants are invertible. (Feel free to post an answer yourself!)

Comment: $\text{constants} - \{0\}$ :)

Comment: Yep! Which is precisely when there is no $b_0$ such that $a_0b_0 = 1$.

You've still got the infinite sums up though. You want to be careful with those, because if you're working with power series, and not just polynomials, you actually get more invertible elements. For example, $1-x$ is actually invertible because you have $1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots$ so you really don't want those infinite sums if you're only working with polynomials!